# how do I capitalise and underscore a variable with resharper live templates

Tags: c#, resharper

I use resharpen live templates a lot - but a problem I am running into - I really want an editable variable such that if I type:

```
the thing works
```

somewhere else I will get: TheThingWorks - or as close to that as possible.   There are two things I have found and tried - **value of another variable with spaces replaced with _** and **value of another variable with first letter capitalised** - but I want to use them together.  If I create

- $description$ - editable
- $descriptionA$ - $description$ capitalised
- $descriptionB$ - $descriptionA$ replaced with underscores

I get as close as I think I'm likely to - but the problem is - I only want to use $description$ and $descriptionB$ in my template - I can't just have an intermediate value floating around somewhere.  And of course if I remove $descriptionA$ from the template - it goes away.

Is there any way to use essentially more than one transform?  Or is there some sort of general purpose transform, eg value of variable passed through this regex?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of  But writing a R#/Rider plugin is pretty straight-forward - maybe [this project](https://github.com/matkoch/resharper-fluentassertions) inspires you